# phonegap android keyboard plugin - set specific keyboard type when using jquery focus

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-keypad

I'm developing a phoengap app with Jquery Mobile.

I've included the following plugin into my android phonegap app to show and hide the android keyboard.
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/SoftKeyboard/SoftKeyBoard.java

This works to show or hide the keyboard, but I'm unable to get a specific keybaord type to pop up based on the input type, ex) email, number, spelling correct, ect.

When selecting an input using $("input").focus(), I'm using the android plugin to show the keyboard, but the keyboard is always the incorrect type.

The only way I can get the keyboard to change to the correct type is if the user explicitly touches the input.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?  I see that using IMEOptions and the EditText field you are able to set a specific keyboard, but I'm using html input's, not native android EditText inputs.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

I would like to use the native keyboard and not a javascript/html keyboard if possible, but be able to configure the keyboard type when I auto pop the keyboard up using jquery focus.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I ended up giving up after spending way to much time trying to get this to work.  I only use the plugin to hide the keyboard on input blur.  I make the user select the input with a touch which then triggers the correct keyboard to open.